# How do I install the sns3 extension in ns3?

Tags: python, c, installation

I can't acccess website https://www.sns3.org, so I not sure how to use and install it.Please help me!
I want to use this extension pack to implement satellite emulation.And dose anyone know how to connect STK to ns3?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/sns3/sns3-satellite) work?

Comment: Let me try.Thank you very much!